# Enable "Render layers in parallel using many CPU cores" from python console QGIS

Tags: qgis, parallel-processing, qgis-python-console

How can I enable "Render layers in parallel using many CPU cores" option from QGIS python console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QThread
# parallel rendering
QSettings().setValue("/qgis/parallel_rendering", True)
```

for use max cores

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
threadcount = QThread.idealThreadCount()
QgsApplication.setMaxThreads(threadcount)
```

And extra for use OpenCL acceleration

```
QSettings().setValue("/core/OpenClEnabled", True)
```